# How can I position dockedItems next to each other in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, button, extjs, layout, panel

I have this tree panel that contains 3 dockedItems: a textfield and 2 buttons:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6auVs.jpg

Some sample code:

```
Ext.defin('treePanel', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
dockedItems: [{
xtype: 'textfield'
},
{
xtype: 'button'
},
{
xtype: 'button'
}]
});
```

What I want is to make the items look like the firefox and chrome search bar when you press Ctrl+F. That means I want to have my textfield and on the right 2 buttons one with "<" and one with ">". Same height as the textfield and they should be squared. If you press Ctrl+F on your browser you'll understand. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for using toolbar.

If you really cannot use toolbar, for whatever reason, you can use a container with hbox layout and place your textfield and buttons in it.

Something like this:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'My',

    launch : function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
             title:'Panel with docked container'
            ,renderTo:Ext.getBody()
            ,width:400
            ,height:300
            ,dockedItems:[{
                 dock:'top'
                ,xtype:'container'
                ,layout:{
                     type:'hbox'
                    ,align:'stretch'
                }
                ,items:[{
                     xtype:'button'
                    ,text:'Left'
                },{
                     xtype:'textfield'
                    ,flex:1
                },{
                     xtype:'button'
                    ,text:'Right'                   
                }] // eo container items                  
            }] // eo dockedItems
        }); // eo panel create            
    } // eo function launch
});
```

Comment: I ended up using the tbar solution and it worked out nicely. Although I tested yours with the container and it looks good too. I'll keep it in mind for further usage. I'll make yours as the answer 'cause the other guy was kind of a jack.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a tbar, it's a shortcut for creating a docked toolbar:

```
Ext.define('MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'a'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'b'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Yeah my coworkers mentionned that but I was looking to avoid it 'cause there are some changes needed to be done in the code inside the buttons etc. Well if it is the only solutions it can't be helped.

Comment: "Some changes needed to be done in the code inside the buttons". What relevance does that have?

Comment: Well adding a tbar puts another layer of container/component between the tree panel and the buttons/textfield so I have to change all my "inheritance" traversing through .up() and .down() functions etc. There's your relevance.

Comment: Well that wasn't really obvious from what you posted. That's the solution because you want the docked items to be contained in a particular layout.